# Can't connect to SQL Server 2005, even with local Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, windows-server-2003-r2

After setting up a second network adapter in the process of adding some SSL'd sites to ISS, my instance of SQL Server 2005 is no longer accessible - **including through SQL Server Management Studio.**

The specific error I receive is:

```
Cannot connect to xxxxxx.
Additional information:

A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.) (Mycrosoft SQL Server, Error: 233)
```

I've verified the following:

- TCP, Shared Memory, and Named Pipe connections are enabled in Configuration Manager
- Connections to anywhere are enabled in Surface Area Configuration
- Surface Area Configuration didn't list my account as having admin credentials; however, when it tried to connect to the server to fix that the connection failed with the same error as Server Management Studio generated. This unfortunately rules out the fix from [203541](https://serverfault.com/questions/203541/sql-server-management-studio-2005-cant-connect-to-localhost-using-windows-authen).

Very little of what I managed to Google pertained to local connections, and what remained wasn't helpful. Is there any way I can fix this, perhaps by running the server with authentication off long enough to fix my permissions a la MySQL?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [start SQL Server in single user mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188236(v=sql.90).aspx) and connect to it that way. Assuming your problem is authenticated-related (I'm not sure it is) this will get you in.

Edit:

Let's try this. Have a look at [SQL Server 2000 installation or local connections fail with "SSL Security error :ConnectionOpen (SECDoClientHandshake())" error message](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309398). I'm finding threads referring to this article by unhappy people who are seeing the same error you are after installing certificates. There's some more background [in this MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/07/26/678596.aspx).

Comment: I've started it in single user mode and I still can't connect, alas.

Comment: Holy. Moly. Your edit did the trick.

Evan, you are absolutely the man. Let me do that again, actually: the MAN. If I'd thought to ask eight hours ago your wisdom would have kept me sane! ;)

Comment: @Sudowned - Glad I could help out.